# Using stdout without stdio.h header file

Tags: c, stdio

So I am trying to convert a C program that uses standard libraries to a standalone application (it is an assignment). This involves writing simple functions for `printf`, `malloc`, `free` and etc. While working on this, I came across a problem of converting `fflush(stdout)` because `stdout` is included in `stdio.h` and must be replaced with something else.

Naturally, I looked at the macro in `stdio.h` which looked like:

```
#define stdout   (__iob[1])
```

I used this macro declaration in my C file, removed the `stdio.h` header, and tried to compile it, but it gave an error `__iob` is undeclared. When I looked at the source file more in detail, there was a data structure:

```
extern struct __file *__iob[];
```

With this included, when compiled, it gives another error below and I am not sure what to make of this:

```
/tmp/ccOTmFBR.o: In function `func1':
program.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `__iob'
/tmp/ccOTmFBR.o: In function `func2':
program.c:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `__iob'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

My question is basically what would be the simplest way to replace `fflush(stdout)` in a C program without using the `stdio.h`.

Comment: You are doing this wrong.  If you musn't use stdio, then you musn't use the capabilities defined there.  You will have to re-implement the whole concept of streams if you want to use them.

Comment: @ChrisStratton But I should be able to write simplified versions of ```printf```, ```malloc``` and ```free``` to be used instead of the ones defined in ```stdio.h```. Are you saying ```stdout``` is different from those?

Comment: Sure, lots of embedded developers do that.  You don't necessarily need to implement buffered streams.  If you don't, fflush() is a no-op.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So you are saying I should just delete the ```fflush(stdout)``` from the program entirely. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Read about the distinction between file descriptors vs streams.  If you implement fake non-buffered streams, then you can implement fflush() as an empty function.

Comment: If you are avoiding `stdio.h` you will be using `read` `write` (see: `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`) for I/O functions you can call using basic system calls. You can then use `0, 1 & 2` for `stdin, stdout, stderr` file descriptors.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I remembered using ```1``` for ```stdout``` as an argument for ```write()``` but did not know it could be used as a general way to refer to the standard output. It seems to work. Thanks.

Comment: if the code is going to use write(), read(), etc then the linker will still need to include the libc library.  so you are not really gaining anything by not using the system header files.